# Uploading files from ASP.NET app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk, I get this error: the page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, file-upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My ASP.NET application is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it provides functionality for uploading files and after that they are stored on S3 Buckets.

When I test my application on localhost, everything works properly and large files are uploaded successfully. But on the live version I get this error:

[The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGaso.png)

I found an [article](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-resolve-error-413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-and-amazon-elasticbeanstalk/) which says that I could add an environment property with key `NGINX_CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE` and a value for the max file size. It didn't work.

Then I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlx9vZN3fWs) and tried to SSH into the EC2 instance but I get this error:

[powershell-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miUuF.png)

The security groups of the EC2 instance are configured to accept SSH from all ipv4 and ipv6. The keypair is also attached to the Elastic Beanstalk.

I then tried to use the Session Manager [session-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTT2L.png). It opens a new tab which looks like this: [session-manager-tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpNu1.png). I'm new to this type of things so I might sound ridiculous, but it looks like it is a windows environment, while the [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlx9vZN3fWs) I mentioned earlier is about fixing this problem on a nginx server (I guess).

I have been stuck on this problem for the last few days, so I'll be very happy if someone helps me. Thank you!